# Simple Chat in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sockets

I want to make a simple client-server stuff in Ruby. I think about something like simple chat where clients can communicate with each other through this 'server'.

Of course I've googled but there are many materials for C/Java/C++ but almost nothing about Ruby.

Any ideas where I should start? Can you reccomend me some good materials for beginer programmers in this topic? 
I just want to better understand the problem of this application and learn the basic of Ruby sockets and stuff I will need to face.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link for [tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/ruby-tcp-chat/) that explains how to build Ruby TCP chat.

> Today, we are going to build a little TCP ruby chat application using the ruby standard library Socket.

By the way, it's the first link in Google for 'Ruby chat' query =)

Answer (score 0):

If you are already a decent Ruby dev, then I can recommend [Working With TCP Sockets](http://www.jstorimer.com/products/working-with-tcp-sockets).